# Revert theme to default

Tags: highcharts

How can I revert my theme back to the default one in Highcharts after I have applied some theme?

I tried this but doesn't work.

```
Highcharts.theme = {
};
var highchartsOptions = Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
```

I tried also the solution described [here](http://www.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5586)

> removing all of the color options from the code below and reloading
>   the Highcharts object will make it default to the basic theme

...but it doesn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unforunately you need to overwrite all colors / parameters with default values for a second chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/WNGpQ/2/

```
 var theme = {
  colors: ['#2f7ed8', '#0d233a', '#8bbc21', '#910000', '#1aadce', '#492970',
        '#f28f43', '#77a1e5', '#c42525', '#a6c96a'],
   chart: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      borderWidth: 0,
      plotBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      plotShadow: false,
      plotBorderWidth: 0
   },
   title: {
      style: {
            color: '#274b6d',//#3E576F',
            fontSize: '16px'
      }
   },
   subtitle: {
      style: {
            color: '#4d759e'
       }
   },
   xAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      lineColor: '#C0D0E0',
      tickColor: '#C0D0E0',
      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#666',
            cursor: 'default',
            fontSize: '11px',
            lineHeight: '14px'
         }
      },
      title: {
         style: {
                color: '#4d759e',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      }
   },
   yAxis: {
      minorTickInterval: null,
      lineColor: '#C0D0E0',
      lineWidth: 1,
      tickWidth: 1,
      tickColor: '#C0D0E0',
      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#666',
            cursor: 'default',
            fontSize: '11px',
            lineHeight: '14px'
         }
      },
      title: {
         style: {
                color: '#4d759e',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      }
   },
   legend: {
      itemStyle: {
            color: '#274b6d',
            fontSize: '12px'
      },
      itemHoverStyle: {
         color: '#000'
      },
      itemHiddenStyle: {
         color: '#CCC'
      }
   },
   labels: {
      style: {
            color: '#3E576F'
        }
   },

   navigation: {
      buttonOptions: {
         theme: {
            stroke: '#CCCCCC'
         }
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: do you have the sample colors that will revert it to default?